# Orderer not found error while sending transaction at high rate in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, raft, hyperledger-caliper

I have a Hyperledger configured with 1 Org, 2 Peers, 5 Orderers (Raft cluster). The network has one channel with a simple chaincode.

While sending transactions to the network using Hyperledger Caliper (with upto 7 clients), It works fine for a lower number of Transactions per second. When I increase the TPS to above 60, it throws the following error for some transactions.

```
2019-07-10T08:20:58.651Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://orderer2-hlf:7050
2019-07-10T08:20:58.652Z - error: [Orderer.js]: Orderer grpcs://orderer2-hlf:7050 has an error Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://orderer2-hlf:7050 
(node:585) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://orderer2-hlf:7050
    at checkState (/opt/caliper/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:833:16)
(node:585) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 42)
```

Increasing the orderer count reduces the number of rejected transactions. This looks like the buffer limitation in the orderer.

Fabric claims to have around 1000 TPS, but I can't go beyond 90 TPS (Updating state using chaincode). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone can give a direct answer to your question. THE Fabric paper presented measurements using some really powerful machines (I think around 32 CPU cores per node). And it used Kafka ordering since Raft hasn't been implemented at that time.

You have two (not mutually exclusive) choices: scale the ordering service horizontally (more Raft nodes) and/or vertically (stronger machines).

Answer (score 0):

> Try something with more Hardware specs
>   4 or more CPUs
>   8 or more GB rams